# How to get a product review form form key in magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, form-key, product-review

I want form key of product review form in magento 1.9 , Can anyone tell me how to get product wise formkey programatically.

Answer (score 0):

You just need put this code:

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
```

into file template/review/form.phtml

Comment: I have small doubt, <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left') ?></div> what is the file 'left', how can i edit that.

Comment: I want product review form key in external file not in template/review/form.phtml any idea ??

Answer (score 0):

**Add in your form**

```
<input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />
```